# Group Tuples Into List

Tags: python, tuples

In Python, what is the best approach to group tuples with a common index?

```
(2, 3, 'z')
(1, 1, 'abc')
(2, 1, 'stu')
(1, 2, 'def')
(2, 2, 'vxy')
```

Result would be:

```
[((1, 1, 'abc'),(1, 2, 'def')]
[((2, 1, 'stu'),(2, 2, 'vxy'), (2, 2, 'vxy')]
```

The goal is to concatenate the 3rd element into a single string object.

Here is the concat part, but I am not sure on the grouping.

```
def sort_tuples(list_input):
    new = sorted(list_input)
    str = ''
    for i in range(0, len(new)):
        str = str + new[i][2]
    return str
```

Comment: What happened to `(2, 3, 'z')`? Why is `(2, 2, 'vxy')` repeated? Where is the concatenation of the 3rd elements that you speak about?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to group; pick your grouping element and append what you want to concatenate to a list per key:

```
groups = {}
for first, second, third in list_input:
    groups.setdefault(first, []).append(third)
```

Then you can just concatenate each list:

```
for key, group in groups.items():
    print(key, ''.join(group))
```

Since you only wanted to concatenate the third element of each tuple, I didn't bother with including the second element in the dictionary, but you are free to store the whole tuple in the group lists too.

Demo:

```
>>> list_input = [
...     (2, 3, 'z'),
...     (1, 1, 'abc'),
...     (2, 1, 'stu'),
...     (1, 2, 'def'),
...     (2, 2, 'vxy'),
... ]
>>> groups = {}
>>> for first, second, third in list_input:
...     groups.setdefault(first, []).append(third)
... 
>>> for key, group in groups.items():
...     print(key, ''.join(group))
... 
1 abcdef
2 zstuvxy
```

If the second key was being used as a *sorting* key, then you'll have to include that when grouping; you can then sort and extract the third:

```
groups = {}
for first, second, third in list_input:
    groups.setdefault(first, []).append((second, third))

for key, group in groups.items():
    print(key, ''.join([third for second, third in sorted(group)]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> groups = {}
>>> for first, second, third in list_input:
...     groups.setdefault(first, []).append((second, third))
... 
>>> for key, group in groups.items():
...     print(key, ''.join([third for second, third in sorted(group)]))
... 
1 abcdef
2 stuvxyz
```

Since this involves sorting, you may as well sort the whole input list once, and use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your input after sorting:

```
from itertools import groupby

for key, group in groupby(sorted(list_input), key=lambda t: t[0]):
    print(key, ''.join([third for first, second, third in group]))
```

Once more, a demo of this approach:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for key, group in groupby(sorted(list_input), key=lambda t: t[0]):
...     print(key, ''.join([third for first, second, third in group]))
... 
1 abcdef
2 stuvxyz
```

The dictionary grouping approach is a O(N) algorithm), as soon as you add sorting it becomes an O(NlogN) algorithm.